# Lua: understanding table array part and hash part

Tags: lua, interpreter, language-implementation, luajit

In section 4, Tables, in The [Implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) there is and example:
`local t = {100, 200, 300, x = 9.3}`

So we have `t[4] == nil`. If I write `t[0] = 0`, this will go to **hash part**.
If I write `t[5] = 500` where it will go? **Array part** or **hash part**?
I would eager to hear answer for Lua 5.1, Lua 5.2 and LuaJIT 2 implementation if there is difference.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? It's an implementation detail. Lua handles sparse arrays just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contiguous integer keys starting from 1 always go in the array part.

Keys that are not positive integers always go in the hash part.

Other than that, it is unspecified, so you cannot predict where `t[5]` will be stored according to the spec (and it may or may not move between the two, for example if you create then delete `t[4]`.)

LuaJIT 2 is slightly different - it will also store `t[0]` in the array part.

If you need it to be predictable (which is probably a design smell), stick to pure-array tables (contiguous integer keys starting from 1 - if you want to leave gap use a value of `false` instead of `nil`) or pure hash tables (avoid non-negative integer keys.)

Comment: Pointing out a functional distinction in the characteristics of tables, the use of the default `#t` only makes sense if the positive integer keys are kept contiguous. As @lhf says, the rest is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from *Implementation of Lua 5.0*

> The array part tries to store the values corresponding to integer keys from 1 to some limit n.Values corresponding to non-integer keys or to integer keys outside the array range are
>   stored in the hash part.

The index of the array part starts from 1, that's why `t[0] = 0` will go to hash part.

> The computed size of the array part is the largest nsuch that at least half the slots between 1 and n are in use (to avoid wasting space with sparse arrays) and there is at least one used slot between n/2+1 and n(to avoid a size n when n/2 would do).

According from this rule, in the example table:

```
local t = {100, 200, 300, x = 9.3}
```

The array part which holds 3 elements, may have a size of 3, 4 or 5. (EDIT: the size should be 4, see @dualed's comment.)

Assume that the array has a size of 4, when writing `t[5] = 500`, the array part can no longer hold the element `t[5]`, what if the array part resize to 8? With a size of 8, the array part holds 4 elements, which is equal to (so, not less that) half of the array size. And the index from between n/2+1 and n, which in this case, is 5 to 8, has one element:`t[5]`. So an array size of 8 can accomplish the requirement. In this case, `t[5]` will go to the array part.

Comment: It can't be the size 3 or 5, as the array part has a size of `2^m`, according to http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf page 19, so it would be 4

Comment: @dualed Thanks, I thought so, but hadn't got proof on it.