# Removing First Value in Checkbox Table

Tags: checkbox, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I am making a program in Lua that has a large amount of checkboxes. Each checkbox is ID-ed from 1 to 100 in the order they appear. When a checkbox is checked, a table saves the checkbox ID and sorts it, and when it is unchecked, the table is searched for that checkbox ID and then removes it if it finds it and then sorts the table again.

However, I am having problems with the first value not removing itself. It will get removed if I check an earlier ID value and then uncheck it, but not if I try unchecking it first.

Here is the code:

```
switchCounter = 0
switchID = {}

--if checkbox-is-checked then
    switchID[switchCounter] = checkbox.id
    switchCounter = switchCounter + 1
    table.sort(switchID)

--elseif checkbox-is-unchecked then
  for p = 0, #switchID do
    if switchID[p] == checkbox.id then
      table.remove(switchID, p)
    end
  end
  switchCounter = #switchID+1
  table.sort(switchID)
```

The table is not altered or touched after this point (yet). It works perfectly as long as it is not the first value I am trying to remove, upon which nothing happens.

This code is utilizing the Corona SDK if that is relevant to answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing Lua by starting your table index at 0. In Lua, tables are 1-indexed, unlike what you're used to from most programming languages. Unfortunately, *most* of this code *actually still works* even though you're using the wrong index range. However, when you call `table.remove` on the *first* element, since your first element has index 0, you'll end up calling `table.remove(switchID, 0)`, at which point Lua looks at you with a raised eyebrow and proceeds to do...absolutely nothing. 0 isn't a valid table index to Lua, so it doesn't remove your first element.

Change your indices to start at 1 and all should be well:

```
switchCounter = 1
switchID = {}

--if checkbox-is-checked then
    switchID[switchCounter] = checkbox.id
    switchCounter = switchCounter + 1
    table.sort(switchID)

--elseif checkbox-is-unchecked then
  for p = 1, #switchID do
    if switchID[p] == checkbox.id then
      table.remove(switchID, p)
    end
  end
  switchCounter = #switchID+1
  table.sort(switchID)
```

**EDIT:** See nobody's excellent remarks below for better information about Lua's stance on indexing.

Comment: Thanks! Crazy that for all this time I've been using Lua, I've never known the table indexing starts at 1 and yet never run into a problem like this. Appreciate it!

Comment: Heh, I've been using Lua for quite a while and was totally baffled when I opened the interpreter and started playing with tables to figure out what was going wrong here...I had no idea so much would _still work_ with 0-indexing even though it's not supposed to! ._. Learning experience for both of us!

Comment: (1/2) Lua tables _do not care_ what keys you use. If you use tables as arrays, you can start at 0,1,23,-42,…, go in steps of 1,-0.25,5,…, you can use "a","b",…"aa","ab",… or whatever you like – it doesn't matter. Neither the table nor Lua care. (So it's _not_ not supposed to work!) But the standard `table` library (and `#` and `ipairs`) are wholly different beasts: They're _very_ opinionated. For them, tables / arrays / "sequences" _MUST_ start at 1, increment by 1, and there mustn't be any gaps (`nil`s) in what's considered the array. That's why things work… until you use these functions.

Comment: (2/2) You can write your own array library / replace `ipairs` / … if you like and make it work differently – Lua is totally fine with that, and I've done that once or twice where it made sense. _In general_ however, that doesn't make sense as everything else (`string` library, `debug` library, …) is also 1-based. [The "Lua doesn't care" bit isn't 100% true – there's a small optimization for the 1-based array so that it takes a bit less memory/time. But that's just a "faster if you comply", not "complete breakage if you deviate" and can be ignored if you don't need it / save more elsewhere.]

Comment: @nobody Thanks for the information, that does make a lot of sense given what I was seeing in the interpreter.  I didn't realize that the table would still act as an array even with an arbitrary integral starting index; my first thought on seeing the above was actually that the initial [0] was being put into the hash component of the table (naturally I was surprised when #tbl returned the right result).  Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: @JoshParnell Well… (that is specifically the optimization (or lack of) I was referring to:) The `(0,some_value)` entry is indeed stored in the "hash part". But that is the normal behavior for a table, and that entries `(1,other_value)`,`(2,etc)`,… silently _drop their keys_ & are stored in an "array part" is an implementation detail that you (generally) shouldn't be worrying about too much. At the language level, it's simply a table. (All these alternate array schemes I described above would dump most slots into the "hash part". And usually, the timing difference doesn't matter.)

Comment: @nobody Fascinating. I didn't believe that first bit until I went _back_ in and re-checked...now I'm seeing that #tbl is indeed one off when 0 is keyed.  I would say, then, that this is a slightly larger opinionation.  To get a true array, you _do_ have to start at 1. You're right though, it's an implementation detail and no one outside of high-perf domains should be worrying about it. I just happen be one of the unlucky ones living in that 16ms world (naturally LuaJIT is involved) :P

Comment: @JoshParnell Oh… well… LuaJIT is _differently_ opinionated: IIRC the "array part" in its tables _does_ start at 0 (even though its `table` library still expects 1-based arrays.)

Comment: @nobody Well, that's only if you're allocating C-style arrays via FFI (which of course makes sense in that case). It doesn't alter the indexing behavior of standard tables, though. I rather wish it did...could really use some perf boost when it comes to iterating over standard tables :/

Comment: @JoshParnell Nope: http://repo.or.cz/luajit-2.0.git/blob/HEAD:/src/lj_tab.c#l133 or also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/17570506/805875

Comment: @nobody Well I'll be. Mind if I borrow the chunk of your brain that houses Lua knowledge for a day or two? :)